# Dstream output to Rabbitmq

Tags: python, apache-spark, rabbitmq, spark-streaming

I am using spark 2.0 (python). I am trying to send the output stream to Rabbitmq. Following is my implemetation,

```
def sendPartition(iter):
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.URLParameters('amqp://user:pass@ip:5672/'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    for record in iter:
        channel.basic_publish(exchange='ExchangePostingUpdate',
                              routing_key='PostingUpdate',
                              body=json.dumps(record)
                              )

    channel.close()

data_stream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreachPartition(lambda partition:sendPartition(partition,rabbitconnection)))
```

It is working fine. But as we see here it is estabilshing connection and closing it for every partition. Is there any better way to do this ?

i tried to estabilsh a connection and pass to `sendPartition(iter,conn)` but i did not work.